# pick image from internet in flutter

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I wonder whether is any way to pick images from web in a flutter app??
I'm looking for something like whats app image picker

[something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql87e.png)

I've looked for many libraries but I didn't get what I'm looking for.

Comment: You mean load image from url? can you post an example or screenshot of what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Do you mean you want to search and use images from the web? Maybe you should look into some API that provides images.

Comment: Do you want to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use available APIs such as Google Images API, which will provide images based on search request. [Google Search API](https://serpapi.com/images-results) There are plenty of it available.